# Should and Could

Tags: differences, word-usage

Should and Could. 
Both are used to indicate the possibility of a situation then what is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Should means something is morally right.
Could means something is possible.

Comment: In some cases, yes. In others, no. Deontic ("moral") _should_ is more common than epistemic ("logical"), true; but _could_ is normally about abilities and willingness, rather than logical possibilities. _Could_ is the one you use in requests _Could you come help me move Thursday?_

Answer (score 2):

"should" often implies obligation, just the same as "must", *but tones it down*. In regular conversations, "should" is common, unless spoken with authority.

"could" implies possibility or a soft recommendation.

Examples:

You should (must) apply for the position.
You could (you possibly can, or have what it takes to) apply for the position.

Comment: Like the 'soft recommendation'.

Answer (score 0):

Although commonly heard "could you help me?", it invites the pedant's response, "I could but I won't."
Speaking and writing clearly are difficult. It is a good rule to say what one means. A bank robber doesn't ask, "could you put the money in the bag?"
All this aside,  I recognize "could" is used to make a request more gentle. But that can be accomplished without murdering the language, "would you be kind enough to ......?"